# WPF variable ammount of elements

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm creating my own slider template and style. It's similar to the basic slider but the track bar contains circles (Ellipses) with a proper separation. The number of circles in the bar should be such that the slider thumb will stop exactly over them.

In a quick approximation, there should be Slider.Maximum - Slider.Minimum / StepSize Ellipses in the control. But, to my knowledge, there is no way to specify a variable number of anything from xaml, is there?

This is, in summary, the code that represents what I'd want to achieve:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="SliderHorizontal" TargetType="{x:Type Slider}">
        <Grid Height="4">
            <Border x:Name="TrackBackground">
                <Rectangle x:Name="PART_SelectionRange" Fill="{StaticResource SliderThumb.Track.BackgroundSelected}" 
                           HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0 0 16 0" Visibility="Hidden"/>
            </Border>
            <Grid>
                <!-- Have a variable ammount of column definitions and ellipses -->
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="4"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    ...
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="4"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Ellipse Grid.Column="0" Fill="White"/>
                ...
                <Ellipse Grid.Column="X" Fill="White"/>
            </Grid>
            <Track x:Name="PART_Track">
                <Track.Thumb>
                    ...
                </Track.Thumb>
            </Track>
        </Grid>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            ...
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

My code so far allows me to use a fixed ammount of ellipses, which looks very bad when it doesn't match the values that are represented by a slider.

I'm new to WPF so I don't know what doing this from code-behind would entail. Can I simply create a class inheriting from Slider and add the Ellipses there? If so, could I get a simple example doing it?

Comment: This doesn't relate directly to your question, but if you are new to WPF, you should check out some tutorials on using the MVVM pattern.  WPF will be significantly easier to work with that way, and you will thank yourself later for learning it early.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `ItemsControl` can display a variable amount of something. Bind its `ItemsSource` property to a collection of the things you want to display, and use its `ItemTemplate` property to determine how they're displayed.

Here's a rough implementation that you should be able to fine tune. In particular, `TickConverter` should be `IMultiValueConverter`, with `Minimum`, `Maximum`, and `TickFrequency` bound separately via a `MultiBinding` -- that way, it'll get automagically reinvoked when any of those properties changes.

```
public class TickConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var slider = (Slider)value;

        var tickOffsets = new List<double>();

        var sliderRange = (slider.Maximum - slider.Minimum);

        var tickcount = (int)Math.Floor(sliderRange / slider.TickFrequency);

        return Enumerable.Range(0, tickcount);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Template:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Slider}" x:Key="SliderHorizontal">
    <ControlTemplate.Resources>
        <local:TickConverter x:Key="TickConverter" />
    </ControlTemplate.Resources>
    <Grid Height="4">
        <Border x:Name="TrackBackground">
            <Rectangle 
                x:Name="PART_SelectionRange"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                Margin="0 0 16 0" 
                Visibility="Hidden"
                />
        </Border>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ItemsControl
                Grid.Column="0"
                ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Converter={StaticResource TickConverter}}"
                >
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <!-- UniformGrid spaces items out evenly -->
                        <UniformGrid 
                            Rows="1" 
                            />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <!-- Align left to fill in start tick for each interval -->
                        <Ellipse
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                            Fill="DeepSkyBlue"
                            Width="3"
                            Height="4"
                            />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
            <!-- And add the end tick -->
            <Ellipse
                Grid.Column="1"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                Fill="DeepSkyBlue"
                Width="3"
                Height="4"
                />
        </Grid>
        <!-- 
        I don't know what you were doing with the thumb, but you didn't ask about it
        so I just ignored it. 
        -->
        <Track x:Name="PART_Track" />
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: In this case the ellipses should be encapsulated within the slider so, would this would mean creating a new slider? Else I don't know where the collection would be defined.

Comment: You could write a [value converter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter(v=vs.110).aspx) that would return a collection of floats.

Comment: Well that worked wonders. I didn't know ItemsControl could do this, and uniformgrids are indeed a nice touch